# Is there any way round to make this template specialisation link?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have tried the following hierarchy and it doesn't link. The call to `c->Execute()` is not seen since it seems to be masked by the `Execute` in `Derived` and it doesn't find an adequate type to use. I would have thought that if there was a problem, it would have to show at compilation. I have tried with GCC 4.8 online and with the borland compiler on Windows. The error message is similar in both cases. Something in the order of:

```
/tmp/ccrT5mNy.o:(.rodata._ZTV7DerivedI5TypeCE[_ZTV7DerivedI5TypeCE]+0x10): undefined reference to `Derived<TypeC>::Execute()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would be very grateful for any pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseType 
{
public: 
    BaseType() {}
    virtual void Execute() { std::cout << "BaseType execute..." << std::endl; };

protected:
};

struct TypeA;
struct TypeB;
struct TypeC;

class Derived2 : public BaseType
{
public:
    Derived2() : BaseType() {}
    virtual void Execute() { std::cout << "Derived execute2" << std::endl; }

protected:
};


template <typename T>
class Derived : public BaseType
{
public:
    Derived() : BaseType() {}
    virtual void Execute();

protected:
};

template <typename T>
class GrandChild : public Derived<T>
{
public:
    GrandChild() : Derived<T>() {}
    void Execute();
};

template<>
void Derived<TypeA>::Execute() { std::cout << "Derived execute... TypeA" << std::endl; }
template<>
void Derived<TypeB>::Execute() { std::cout << "Derived execute... TypeB" << std::endl; }
template<>
void GrandChild<TypeC>::Execute() { std::cout << "Derived execute... TypeC" << std::endl; }


int main()
{
    BaseType* a = new Derived<TypeA>();      
    BaseType* b = new Derived<TypeB>();      
    BaseType* c = new GrandChild<TypeC>();      
    BaseType* d2 = new Derived2();
    a->Execute();
    b->Execute();
    c->Execute();
    d2->Execute();

    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
    delete d2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Derived<TypeC>::Execute()` must be defined even if you never call it, since you're instantiating the class template.  Try adding an empty definition, or one that `throw`s, etc. and the program should link and work as you expect.

Comment: It certainly does work by adding the specialisation that you suggest. Thank you very much for the answer.